# Jumping radiobuttons

Tags: javascript, arrays

I need to make "jumping radiobuttons". First radiobutton is checked, rest are disabled and I have to push him 3 positions to right. 
I've declarated array with my inputs but I don't have idea how to code them to make them moving

Answer (score 0):

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#first").click(function() {
    $("#second").attr("disabled", true);
    $("#third").attr("disabled", true);
    $("#fourth").attr("disabled", true);
    $(".move").css({
      "position": "relative",
      "margin-left": "100px"
    });
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<body>
  <div class="command">
    <form method="post" action="traitement.php">
      <input type="radio" name="first" id="first" /> first</br>
      </br>
      <div class="move">
        <input type="radio" name="second" id="second" /> second</br>
        </br>
        <input type="radio" name="third" id="third" /> third</br>
        </br>
        <input type="radio" name="fourth" id="fourth" /> fourth</br>
        </br>
      </div>
    </form>
  </div>
```

If I click the first radio button means, the remaining three radio buttons will be disabled and also three radio buttons are moved to the right side.

You can run this code directly.

Hope, you want this. If not means, explain your question with detail.